# How to escape multiline regex text to valid json?

Tags: javascript, json, regex, python-textfsm

```
Value Year (\d+)
Value Timezone (\S+)
Value MonthDay (\d+)
Value Month (\w+)
Value Time (..:..:..)

Start
  ^${Time}.* ${Timezone} \w+ ${Month} ${MonthDay} ${Year} -> Record
```

This is a template for [texfsm](https://github.com/google/textfsm) which does parsing of cli based responses with a regex template. Heres the return from javascripts json.stringify

```
{"template":"Value Year (\\d+)\nValue Timezone (\\S+)\nValue MonthDay (\\d+)\nValue Month (\\w+)\nValue Time (..:..:..)\n\nStart\n  ^${Time}.* ${Timezone} \\w+ ${Month} ${MonthDay} ${Year} -> Record"}
```

I want to write this template on the front end and then send it to my server for processing. I've used **json.stringify()** but when try and use **json.loads()** in python it compains about improperly escaped characters.

```
ValueError: Invalid \escape: line 1 column 83 (char 82)
```

How can I properly escape this template for json to then unescape it and use it on my server in python?

--

As a side note.

I've seen here how to escape regex (
[Is there a RegExp.escape function in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript)) though I'm a bit unsure on how to unescape it.

Comment: What‘s the output when you use `json.stringify()`?

Comment: That probably would be helpful :D, just updated the post with it. @Anonymous

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape all dollar sign characters.
Change all $ with \$

Comment: Cool. I’ll check that out and let you know what happens.